# Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running? en android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, android-toast

Buen día,

Estoy programando una aplicación algo básica en Android Studio. Alguien podría ayudarme con el error mencionado en el título (No se puede agregar la ventana - el token nulo no es válido; ¿se está ejecutando su actividad?) porque lo que sucede es que cuando llamo al servicio CustomToastService desde mi MainActivity a través de un botón para querer generar una vista superpuesta que usa parámetros de ventana, la ventana con el privilegio que quiero no se muestra generando una excepción. p.ej. TYPE_ACCESSIBILITY_OVERLAY u otras constantes

NOTA: EL CÓDIGO ME FUNCIONA CON EL TIPO DE VENTANA TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY SOLO CON ESTE Y NO OTRO Y TENGO LOS PERMISOS ADECUADOS.

Mi codigo ;

```
package com.sim.lyxx;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

public class CustomToastService extends Service {

    private static final int COUNT = 5;
    private static final int DELAY = 5000; // delimitador en tiempo del overlay1

    private Handler mHandler;
    private Runnable mRunnable;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mHandler = new Handler();
        mRunnable = new Runnable() {
            @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    overlay1(getApplicationContext(), COUNT, LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_toast, null, false));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("", "", e);
                    showToast("" + e.getMessage());
                }
                mHandler.postDelayed(this, DELAY);
            }
        };
        mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, DELAY);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);
    }

    private void overlay1(Context context, final int count, final View v) {
        if (context != null) {
            Handler handler = new Handler(context.getMainLooper());
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_ACCESSIBILITY_OVERLAY,
                                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON,
                                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
                        params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
                        wm.addView(v, params);


                        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                wm.removeView(v);


                                if (count > 0) {
                                    mHandler.postDelayed(() -> overlay1(context, count - 1, v), DELAY);
                                }
                            }
                        }, DELAY);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("CustomToastService", "", e);
                        showToast("" + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void showToast(String message) {
        Handler handler = new Handler(getMainLooper());
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}`
```

Lo que he hecho es investigar por qué aparece esta excepción donde he encontrado que generalmente el error ocurre porque es un servicio aunque también lo descarté porque creaba una actividad con la misma lógica y devolvía el mismo resultado, también creí que reemplazando

overlay1(getApplicationContext(), COUNT, LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_toast, null, false));

por

```
overlay1(CustomToastService.this, COUNT, R.layout.custom_toast);
```

o en su defecto

```
overlay1(MainActivity.this, COUNT, R.layout.custom_toast);
```

(que es desde donde llamo al servicio)

pero ningún método funcionó

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estás usando un contexto el cual desaparece cuando quieres hacer uso de él.

> Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity
> running?

**Como te encuentras en un `Servicio`, aquí el contexto es el mismo servicio, por lo que puedes usar simplemente `this` como contexto.**

Por ejemplo, en lugar de usar el contexto de la Activity:

```
overlay1(MainActivity.this, COUNT, R.layout.custom_toast);
```

usa:

```
overlay1(this, COUNT, R.layout.custom_toast);
```